# WWW:Mechanize Form Select

Tags: perl, youtube, screen-scraping, perl-module, www-mechanize

I am attempting to login to Youtube with WWW:Mechanize and use forms() to print out all the forms on the page after logging in.  My script is logging in successfully, and also successfully navigating to Youtube.com/inbox;  However, for some reason Mechanize can not see any forms at Youtube.com/inbox.  It just returns blank.  Here is my code:

```
#!"C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe" -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = CGI->new;

$q->header();

my $url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&continue=http://www.youtube.com/signin%3Faction_handle_signin%3Dtrue%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26hl%3Den_US%26next%3D%252Findex&hl=en_US&ltmpl=sso';

my $mechanize = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck => 1);

$mechanize->agent_alias( 'Windows Mozilla' );

$mechanize->get($url);

$mechanize->submit_form(
        form_id => 'gaia_loginform',
        fields      => { Email => 'myemail',Passwd => 'mypassword' },
    );
    die unless ($mechanize->success);

$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/inbox';

$mechanize->get($url);

$mechanize->form_id('comeposeform');

my $page = $mechanize->content();

print Dumper($mechanize->forms());
```

Mechanize is unable to see any forms at youtube.com/inbox, however, like I said, I can print all of the forms from the initial link, no matter what I change it to...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a Youtube account, so I cannot test run your program. I imagine it is the usual problem of JavaScript generated forms; when you print `$page`, you won't see them in the HTML. If that is indeed the case, either use one of the three JS-capable Mechanize classes, or better, forego screen-scraping and make use of the API instead: see http://youtube.com/dev and [WebService::GData::YouTube](http://p3rl.org/WebService::GData::YouTube).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, one of the best debugging approaches is to `print` what you get and check if it is what you were expecting. This applies to your problem too.

In your case, if you `print $mechanize->content()` you'll see that you didn't get the page you're expecting.  YouTube wants you to follow a JavaScript redirect in order to complete your cross-domain login action. You have multiple options here:

- parse the returned content manually – i.e. `/location\.replace\("(.+?)"/`
- try to have your code parse JavaScript (have a look at [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.020/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod))
- [recommended] use [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages.html#Retrieving_messages) for managing your inbox

Comment: Thanks for the tips alessandro!  The only thing is, when I print the content, it displays the inbox page exactly as I would expect...it just can't see any forms on the page.  How could it display the correct inbox page when I print the content, and be able to view the source of the printed content correctly in the browser (when I view source), but be unable to see that source with www:mechanize?

Comment: @user589294 – If the result of your last `->get` doesn't contain any <form> tag with id="composeform" as you're expecting, then it may be generated via JavaScript as daxim said, or it could be excluded because the server detects you have a non-JavaScript browser, or a lot of other causes given by the complexity of the YouTube application. You could only try to use Firebug and sniff every communication between your browser and the server and mimic it with the Mech. I'm not giving you the solution, I know, but a research method. The only serious advice I can give you is: use the public API.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm now using the public API.  Good advice.